# Hotkeys containing shift not working in AHK

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I have AHK running in a virtual machine (windows 10) under VMWare Fusion on my mac, with a Danish keyboard. Hotkeys such as

```
½::$
!'::@
```

are working fine (for making typed keys match what's printed on the keyboard).

But any hotkeys containing shift (`+`) are not. E.g. `+!9::}`

Am I doing it right?

Suggestions for troubleshooting are also much appreciated.

Comment: I've seen similar that the wrong driver or keyboard is selected in the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Send](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/docs/commands/Send.htm) command

```
+!9:: Send {}}
```

Comment: Beautiful! For future reference: This only works with the left alt key. The righthand one seems to be mapped to AltGr. Adding also `+<^>!9:: Send {}}` solves this.